# Can I use "appearance" in this context?

Tags: nouns, word-usage

I have found the phrase "How Many Times Does a Word Appear in the Bible".
In an XML document I do not want to use the verb *appear*, but rather the corresponding noun.

For Example:

> Appearance of the word "whatever" in book *Whatever*:
>      Chapter 23: 3 times
>      Chapter 30: 2 times

Can I use *appearance* in this context?

Comment: You _can_ but I think "instance," "occurrence" or "frequency" would be better.

Comment: I feel that's not quite the word in the context. You may have better alternatives.

Comment: @kris - it may sound pedantic, but while several options may be available, there can only ever be 1 alternative to anything. :)

Comment: 'Occurrences' I think is best. Also 'something "occurs" twenty-seven times in the article', is perhaps better than "appears".

Comment: And 'How many times does a word 'occur' in the Bible?'.

Answer (score 1):

You would use "appearances." When used to mean "a single instance of [something] appearing," *appearance* is a countable noun, and takes an *s* to form a plural.

You could also use "occurrences," which means the same thing.